# Scanned and text PDF: parallel scrolling and selection in web application

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, canvas

I am currently developing an application to extract information from a 1950's Malaysian magazine written in Arabic script. In order to analyze the content and find links with some other documents, the whole Arabic collection has been scanned and converted in latin script.

I thus have two collections of PDF, one with the images of the scanned documents in Arabic script, and one with the latin transliteration, in text format. I would like to be able to compare each PDF side by side. For this purpose, I would like the scroll of the two PDFs to be locked together.

Moreover, I would like the user to be able to select some text in either document, and this selection to be reflected in the second document. By doing this, the selected latin text can be used to query several databases of annex content. As you can see in the image below, even if the text in the scanned document cannot be selected directly, the paragraphs roughly have the same position in each PDF (as in a mirror since Arabic is written from right to left).

[image: Interface mockup]

I have been looking for technical solutions, and my best shot at the moment is to use two canvas and listen to selection and scroll events to reflect them on the other side. I played with [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/) and it seems that could help me to display PDFs and listen to the events triggered by the user action at the same time. The problem is that the documentation of this library is very scarce and that it seems still in early phases, even if there are very frequent updates.

Do you know of any better solution that would let me realize such a system easily? Please consider the following constraints:

- The system should be usable by the maximum number of people, and to be able to connect to exterior databases, hence the on-web requirement.
- Ideally, it should work in most browsers, specifically Chrome, IE 8 and Firefox 4, as they are the most used browsers in Malaysia ([source: gs statcounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-MY-yearly-2010-2011))
- The arabic script, called Jawi, used is not standard Arabic and cannot be submitted to OCR, as there isn't even any standard encoding (some characters are not even available in Unicode)

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: I've asked a friend to take a look. Perhaps tomorrow...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am looking forward to seeing your answer.

Comment: I made some progress with `pdf.js` and based the viewer of the demo `viewer.html` file included in the source. I'll post my approach here when I will reach a result that complies with my requirements.

Comment: I'ce repeated my request to my friends

Comment: I am currently discussing with the pdf.js developers to find a solution as shown there: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mozilla.dev.pdf-js/Qzq-xA2MHjs The main problem is that I have to locate the position of the text in the canvas in order to allow for parallel selection.

Comment: Did you find anything, as I am interested in solving this also but for totally something different?

Comment: Hello @ChrisTarasovs. Unfortunately I moved away from this project and cannot how I solved this problem if I have even managed to solve it :)